# CSS3 column break after in IE/Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, css-multicolumn-layout

Recently been in need of breaking columns after elements with a class 'hardbreak'. Current solution I've gone with is the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/y9oyrk9x/

```css
.hardbreak {
  display: block;
  -webkit-column-break-after: always;
  -moz-column-break-after: always;
  -ms-column-break-after: always;
  -o-column-break-after: always;
  column-break-after: always;
  break-after: always;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.columns {
  -webkit-column-width: 250px;
  column-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="columns">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
<div class="hardbreak"></div>
  consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus commodo, ante vitae viverra placerat, diam justo vulputate nunc, a condimentum elit nulla sed leo. Etiam ornare nibh dolor, ut interdum neque tempus in. Integer a lorem eu orci suscipit viverra. Aliquam non dolor rhoncus, venenatis diam quis, consectetur nibh. Sed ut vestibulum felis, et lacinia elit. Nulla in quam imperdiet, porta neque vel, tempus elit. Proin ac odio nec urna vehicula placerat. Maecenas congue urna sit amet purus suscipit, at fringilla ipsum venenatis. Curabitur sit amet auctor odio.
  <div class="hardbreak"></div>
  Duis posuere mi quis ipsum interdum malesuada. Donec varius nibh nunc, quis volutpat metus auctor non. Pellentesque tempor lobortis condimentum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris tristique leo mauris. Donec dignissim lorem quis ipsum vehicula consequat. Cras id neque nec risus pretium euismod.

Proin sagittis dolor at quam lobortis, vitae pretium lacus ullamcorper. Donec sagittis vestibulum neque ut viverra. Mauris id ipsum nisl. Maecenas sed hendrerit dui. Sed mattis tincidunt blandit. Ut quis odio mauris. In at convallis leo. Ut libero sem, maximus eget condimentum id, maximus id sem. Fusce rutrum auctor sem a fringilla. Cras ut sagittis odio. Maecenas ac sapien ut velit dictum dignissim. Morbi nisi felis, fringilla sit amet faucibus eu, bibendum et metus. Quisque viverra nisl at accumsan facilisis. Nam molestie dui in porttitor tincidunt. Nam elementum nisl tincidunt, auctor nibh vitae, egestas ante.

Praesent in accumsan tortor. Aenean non diam vitae sem mollis tempor. Suspendisse eu iaculis elit. Sed ex nisi, pretium ut lobortis eget, vulputate in felis. Suspendisse non leo faucibus, sodales lacus pellentesque, lacinia nulla. Phasellus maximus est quis felis condimentum, eu laoreet magna pulvinar. Fusce mollis dui eget bibendum commodo. Aenean nisl ipsum, mollis id nisl id, mattis gravida erat. Ut sem quam, dignissim quis fermentum hendrerit, interdum id sapien.

Nam venenatis aliquet pulvinar. Cras fermentum ut leo et ullamcorper. Proin consequat convallis fermentum. Aliquam vitae ligula ut dolor accumsan luctus sit amet sit amet elit. Pellentesque laoreet sit amet leo eu bibendum. Pellentesque varius est non quam ultricies, vel ullamcorper metus ultricies. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin vitae eros sed mi suscipit fermentum. Suspendisse imperdiet risus ac leo suscipit volutpat. Pellentesque ac tincidunt justo, nec interdum odio. Etiam ultrices augue eu lectus semper, ac volutpat libero auctor. Sed tellus leo, volutpat sed dapibus et, suscipit id ligula. Nullam dictum aliquam congue.

Nam eget orci arcu. Cras tempus arcu consectetur purus ultrices luctus. Fusce vestibulum risus eu justo ornare, eu condimentum elit placerat. Pellentesque vel ex massa. In ullamcorper dolor ut ex volutpat consequat eget id tellus. Proin vitae diam est. Fusce quis metus ultrices, venenatis enim sed, sollicitudin felis. Donec at ullamcorper odio, vel tempus ex. Nam in sapien dui. Donec purus eros, posuere ut dui at, cursus posuere enim. Duis vulputate luctus hendrerit. Vestibulum ut velit eu ex condimentum rutrum. Etiam venenatis iaculis dui. In dignissim neque sit amet ipsum porta dapibus.
</div>
```

So far it works fine on iOS, Safari & Chrome. But i cannot seem to get it working on Firefox or IE. Is there any workaround? Or is it simply not supported?

Comment: Docs on here says it's not supported by most browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/break-after

Comment: Are you trying to get 3 colums with text or what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @LarsMertens I'm trying to break the column & let it continue after a given class. So that i for an example have have 2 paragraphs on first column & let it flow on the rest. Reason for this is that I'm presenting a book - & the authors would like for the possibility of breaking the columns so that they can for an example only show the introduction part on it's own without other content flowing in over it.

Only other solution I've thought of is wrapping all pages in a container, set It's height to be that of the columns & make it display: inline-block on that class.

Comment: That might be a solution if you're only using css. If you have more knowledge about other programming languages i would look for a different approach on this subject if it still fits the project scope. Seems like a more complex problem.